# Sending multiple attachments from NX to an email account?

Tags: email, binary

Previously, I was using **uuencode** command to send multiple attachments from **VNC** to Windows using email and it worked fine.

However, when i try to send multiple attachments from **NX** to Windows using the same command, it did sent a mail but the content of the mail is more like ASCII code.

Is there probably any other way for me to send multiple attachments from **NX** or even other than **VNC** to an email account?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do NX and VNC have to do with email? And what is the problem with “the content of the mail is more like ASCII code” — the point of uuencode *is* to get something that could reasonably be described as “ASCII code”?

Answer (score 0):

For sending multiple attachments in the same message from a Unix/Linux system, you also have the alternative of sending them via the command line.

Using `uuencode` you  just have to concatenate the several uuencoded attachments from the command line; as in:

`(uuencode file1 /dev/null ; uuencode file2 /dev/null ; uuencode file3 /dev/null )| mail  -s "subject" myemail@example.com`

If missing uuencode, to install it on Debian:

```
sudo apt install sharutils
```